# Are there any latex free climbing tapes?

Tags: gear, climbing, crack-climbing, tape-gloves, allergies

My daughter does crack climbing and wanted me to see if I could find some latex free tape. Her hands are sensitive to the latex.

Are there any latex free climbing tapes?

Answer (score 6):

A quick search turned up these possibilities:

#### [Jaybird & Mais Sports Medicine Adhesive Tape (non-stretch)](http://jaybird.com/RigidTape.asp)

Many of the products say: **Hypo-allergenic and 100% Latex Free**

This is not specifically described as climbing tape but the first product, EX1 JAYBIRD® ONE TAPE, says: "Our strongest everyday strapping tape product. EX1 is manufactured using a higher thread count fabric which results in greater tensile strength."  It is currently [available from Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000QD2YEQ)

#### [Cramer 750 Athletic Tape](http://www.cramersportsmed.com/products/taping-amp-wrapping/cramer-750-athletic-tape)

"Cramer 750 is designed to provide high end performance at a budget conscious price.  Latex free adhesive."  I couldn't find a good single-roll price (shipped), but [by the case from Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005929NRU) it is a fraction of the price of the EX1 tape.

Marketing perhaps, but the EX1 sounds like a safer bet since Jaybird make several non-stretch tapes and the EX1 is "[their] strongest" and specifically says "Hypo-allergenic" rather than simply latex-free.

Comment: @Jean I believe this is a good option. Their description of the product as being cloth without discussing any plastic, waxy, or slippery coating makes me think it would be ideal for gymnastics and climbing.

Comment: @Jean You're welcome.  If you get the EX1 tape will you tell me how well it works?